# user.name is ignored by oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am running oozie 4.1.0. While submitting a workflow task, I am setting user.name=mapred in job.properties; However, the job is being submitted with my linux user with which I am submitting from command line. Other parameters in the job.properties seem to get picked up correctly. Please let me know if anyone has ever come across this problem.

Thanks

Comment: If you really want the **workflow** to be owned by `mapred` -- which is an insult to good practices in the Hadoop and Linux world -- then just set env variable `HADOOP_USER_NAME` before submitting from command line. And the **job executions** will also be owned by `mapred`. Which is an abomination.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, this disables usage of `${wf:user()}` in workflows.xml, because desired (by user.name=x) user substituted by linux user (let it be 'y').